# what is the right way to set JVM param's in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jvm-arguments

i am using eclipse 4.2 to execute a junit test.
the test uses a lot of memory so what i want to do is to enlarge the memory allocated to the jvm. i wanted to know if there is a differences between setting the heap memory param's in the eclipse ini file and the run configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note the memory settings for Java processes started by eclipse
are different from the maximum allowed memory size for eclipse itself.

The allowance for eclipse itself is set on startup by

`-vmargs -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m`

Note that the m in "mx" is case sensitive, while the m in "1024M" is
case insensitive; and the single-X options are spelt without "=", but the
double-X options are spelt with "=".

The memory size for JVMs started *by* eclipse, which is what you want to influence unit tests, is set *within* eclipse:

`Window::Preferences::Java::Installed JREs::Edit::Default Vm Arguments: 
    -Xms128M -Xmx2048M`

(Exact titles of menu entries may vary by eclipse version.)

Answer (score 4):

you can increase heap size in `eclipse.ini` file like below.

```
 -Xms1024m
 -Xmx1024m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set it in `eclipse.ini`, it applies to the Eclipse process itself - not to any new Java processes you start from Eclipse.

If you set it in the Run Configuration, it *only* applies to that run configuration, but not to Eclipse itself.

Since your unit test is using a lot of memory, it won't matter how much memory Eclipse has available. The unit test will run in a new Java process, with default memory allocation.