# java heap space error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis

I am getting 16912 records by calling a webservice.When I am trying to write these records in an xml file I am getting

```
[WARN] Unhandled Exception thrown: class org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
Jul 27, 2013 12:46:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/WebserviceApplication] threw exception
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Java heap space
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager > Processes > and End the task 'java.exe'

Restart 'java.exe' from your jre/bin

Restart eclipse

This worked for me.

You can also try modifying Xms and Xmx in eclipse.ini (in the eclipse installtion folder) to: -Xms768m -Xmx768m

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase there are a few tips here [Increasing eclipse memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758010/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-jvm-params-in-eclipse)

But I think that what you will need to do is increase the amount of memory available to your application when it is running, to set up your run configuration you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625060/store-run-configuration-with-project-in-eclipse)

Then you can pass your vm arguments eg -Xms200m -Xmx500m in the arguments tab (I think, one of the tabs anyway).

I would suggest that you have a look at [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), its a java tool for monitoring and analysing your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the max size of the heap by passing the -Xmx option on the command line, for example `java -Xmx2000m MyClass` for a max heap size of 2000mb

Answer (score 0):

You can increase heap size when running application by CMD.

There are basically 3 options whhich u can set

```
 1. -Xms<size>        (startup heap)
 2. -Xmx<size>        (Max heap)
 3. -Xss<size>        (Stack size)

example:
    java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName
```

Comment: I am running my application from eclipse.Will the above solutions work in eclipse

Comment: For eclipse u need to add options in eclipse.ini file present in ECLIPSE_HOME. these are [Steps](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) to set values for JVM. you need to try this. this should work.