# Eclipse Java IDE console

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

How come whenever I click on run, it says in the console in red:

> picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

I'm confused because it never happens to other people who use Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have any environment variable with that name set (in the Run configuration or globally)?

Comment: It says Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M right underneath what I just ran.

Comment: Is there anything else written that can help us help you? This is one of the options Eclipse can start up with; see here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758010/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-jvm-params-in-eclipse

Comment: What's the rest of it say?

Comment: does your `eclipse.ini` file contain something like this "-Xmx512m" if it doesnt you can add the entry there to whatever value you like